# The entity type 'List<Workout>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

My problem is I get this error

> The entity type 'List' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.%22)

I searched about it and did everything.

`id` is public, and the data annotation `[Key]` is there. I don't know what else to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Business_Layer
{
    public class ExerciseType
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public BodyParts TargetetMuscle { get; set; }

        public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

        public List<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }

        public ExerciseType()
        {
             Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
        }

        public ExerciseType(string name, string description, BodyParts targetedmuscle, Equipment equipment)
        {
            Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            TargetetMuscle = targetedmuscle;
            Equipment = equipment;
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Business_Layer
{
    public class Exercise
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Reps { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Status status { get; set; }
        public ExerciseType exerciseType { get; set; }
        public List<Workout> workouts { get; set; }

        public Exercise()
        {
           workouts = new List<Workout>();
        }

        public Exercise(string name, string description,int weight, int reps)
        {
            status = Status.Waiting;
            Weight = weight;
            Reps = reps;
            workouts = new List<Workout>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Business_Layer
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be more than 50 symbols!")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
        public List<Workout> History { get; set; }
      
        public User()
        {
             History = new List<Workout>();
             Workouts = new List<Workout>();
        }

        public User(string name)
        {   
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Name = name;

           History = new List<Workout>();
           Workouts = new List<Workout>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Business_Layer
{
    public class Workout
    {
        [Key]
        public int WorkoutId { get; set; }

        public List<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }

        public User Creator { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }

        public Workout()
        {
           Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
        }

        public Workout(User user)
        {
            Status = Status.Waiting;
            Users = new List<User>();
            Exercises = new List<Exercise>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class TrackerDBContext:DbContext
{
    public TrackerDBContext()
    {
    }

    public TrackerDBContext(DbContextOptions contextOptions) : base(contextOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-PTKBD3O\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=FitnessTrackerDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseType>()
                    .Property(a => a.TargetetMuscle)
                    .HasConversion<string>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseType>()
                    .Property(o => o.Equipment)
                    .HasConversion<string>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasMany(e => e.Workouts)
                    .WithMany(e=>e.Users);//napravi vruzka mejdu history i workouts

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasOne(e => e.History);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Workout>()
                    .HasOne(e => e.Creator);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExerciseType> ExerciseTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(e => e.History);
```

Since `e.History` is a `List<T>`, but mapped as a reference (`HasOne`), EF interprets the type as a mapped type. Then it looks for a property that qualifies as a primary key according to EF's name conventions, and finds none.

Obviously, the mapping should be:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(e => e.History);
```

Adhering to common naming conventions (use plural names for collection properties) might have helped prevent this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as it treats your List as if you intended to establish new column in db of type List. Try to define all necessary relations in OnModelCreating, and add FK in model class.